# Why utf8.Validstring function not detecting invalid unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, go, utf-8

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points, I got to know that U+D800 through U+DFFF are invalid. So in decimal system, it is 55296 through 57343.

And Maximum valid Unicode is '\U0010FFFF'. In decimal system, it is 1114111

My code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unicode/utf8"

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Case 1(Invalid Range)")
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%c", rune(55296+1))
    if !utf8.ValidString(str) {
        fmt.Print(str, " is not a valid Unicode")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(str, " is valid unicode character")
    }

    fmt.Println("Case 2(More than maximum valid range)")
    str = fmt.Sprintf("%c", rune(1114111+1))
    if !utf8.ValidString(str) {
        fmt.Print(str, " is not a valid Unicode")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(str, " is valid unicode character")
    }
}
```

Why ValidString function is not returning false for invalid unicode characters given as input ? I am sure my understanding is wrong, could some one explain??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem happens in Sprintf. Since you give it an invalid character Sprintf replaces with with `rune(65533)` which is the unicode replacement character used instead of invalid characters. So your string is valid UTF8.

This will also happen if you do something like this: `str := string([]rune{ 55297 })` so this might be something that happens when creating runes. It's not immediately obvious from: https://blog.golang.org/strings

If you want to force your string to contain invalid UTF8 you can write the first string like this:

```
str := string([]byte{237, 159, 193})
```

Answer (score 2):

You take an invalid value and convert it using Sprintf. It's converted to the error value. You then check the error value, which is a valid Unicode code point.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Case 1: Invalid Range")
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%c", rune(55296+1))
    fmt.Printf("%q %X %d %d\n", str, str, []rune(str)[0], utf8.RuneError)
    if !utf8.ValidString(str) {
        fmt.Print(str, " is not a valid Unicode")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(str, " is valid unicode character")
    }

    fmt.Println("Case 2: More than maximum valid range")
    str = fmt.Sprintf("%c", rune(1114111+1))
    fmt.Printf("%q %X %d %d\n", str, str, []rune(str)[0], utf8.RuneError)
    if !utf8.ValidString(str) {
        fmt.Print(str, " is not a valid Unicode")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(str, " is valid unicode character")
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Case 1: Invalid Range
"�" EFBFBD 65533 65533
�  is valid unicode character
Case 2: More than maximum valid range
"�" EFBFBD 65533 65533
�  is valid unicode character
```